# Firebird 'Open database xxxxxxx failed' error

Tags: odbc, firebird

I am using Firebird ODBC Driver v2.0 64 bit to connect to a FB 2.5.2 64 bit instance on a Win 7 Home Premium 64 bit 'server' from a Win 7 Pro laptop. The database is on a drive local to the 'server.'

When I test connect, I get 'Connected.'

When my application (home grown) uses the ODBC connection, it gets the 'Open database xxxxxxx failed' error message.

The same thing happens when a Wim 8 laptop connects.

BUT! My Win 8 PC connects!

I have EMS's SQLManager on the Win 7 laptop and it CAN connect & manage the DB.

I have scoured the Internet and tried every 'solution' that I could find.

Does anyone know the REAL ssolution to this delima?

Comment: Is the application 32 bit or 64 bit, is the OS on your laptop 32 bit or 64 bit, did you use the 32 bit or 64 bit ODBC administrator + Firebird driver to setup the DSN?

Comment: The app is 32 bit, all the OSes are 64 bit, FB on the server is 64 bit, 64 bit ODBC (FB 32 bit ODBC is NOT installed.)

Comment: To use odbc from a 32 bit app, you need the 32 bit fbclient and 32 bit odbc driver. A 32 bit application cannot load nor use 64 bit libraries in its address space.

Comment: Them something impossible is happening. Both my dev box (Win 8 64 bit) and the 'server' (win 7 64 bit) are connecting the 32 bit app to the 64 bit Firebird instance. On the client side, both the 32 & 64 bit ODBC connections will Test Connect from the ODBC manager. But the app will connect to the DB only with the 64 bit ODBC connection.

Comment: I am not talking about the bitness of the Firebird server, that is irrelevant because the ODBC driver and the database server are decoupled by the wire protocol (over TCP/IP). When you use ODBC, the ODBC driver is loaded into the address space of your client application, therefor the bitness of the application and the ODBC driver **must** match, otherwise it simply will not work.